# Having trouble installing CASA

Tags: command-line, bash, software-installation

I downloaded the release package (tarball) from NRAO website and unpacked it and made a directory as said in the website. Then I wanted to create a path for it, so I edited the .bashrc file with `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin/CASA/(appropriate package)`, but I still couldn't run CASA. When I type `casapy` it says `command not found`. As my friends suggested I entered the respective directory and typed `./casa` but the terminal returns:

```
ERROR: Unable to detect CASA_INSTALLATION_DIRECTORY.
Please report this to CASA developers immediately.
./casa: 112: exit: Illegal number: -1
```

Comment: From the error message "`ERROR: Unable to detect CASA_INSTALLATION_DIRECTORY`", 1. You should report it to the developers. 2. Perhaps add `EXPORT CASA_INSTALLATION_DIRECTORY=whatever` to your `.bashrc`. 3. Reread the `CASA` documentation, `README*` files. etc.

Comment: Reported it and waiting for their response. Did all other ways so far discussed in the internet and same error displays all the time. Anyway thank you for your response waltinator. Suggest me any other way to rectify that if u know.